# How to let users get their information on my site that would usually on another one using Preact and JS

Tags: javascript, preact

I'm sorry if my question is vague.

At the moment I am trying to make an app with Preact. One piece of functionality I would like is for the user to be able to enter their name for example on my app and then my app would communicate with a different website(i have no control over) to retrieve the persons information. The other website has an .aspx form where a person would usually enter their name themselves. Preferably with JS.

Comment: forms usually `POST` to their server with the appropriate key/vals. Just send a `POST` to that same endpoint, filling in the same info from your form. **Note:** It probably won't be this easy, the 3rd part website can do many things to make sure it was actually _their_ form that sent the message, not some random software like you `POST`ing to them. I would skip this method and start by speaking to the 3rd party about any API's they have.

Comment: do you have the exact endpoint for the other website where you'll get the info from? Also do they allow CORS(your domain) to get the info from their site directly? Just asking as it feels like you want to imitate their functionality but do not have the exact endpoints to do so